# ExtendedMapView cause crash - android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm using an extended MapView class i called ExtendedMapView, which will contain along the MapView also the currentLocation. However the class causes crash on caliing.

here is part of the MapActivity class which causes the crush:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    map=(ExtendedMapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);}
```

the ExtendedMapView Class:

```
package com.sit.augmented_reality.map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class ExtendedMapView extends MapView {

private Location currentLocation;

public ExtendedMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
    super(context, apiKey);
     }

public void setCurrentLocation (Location location)
{
    currentLocation = location;
}

public Location getCurrentLocation ()
{
    return currentLocation;
}

}
```

The Layout XML (map.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.sit.augmented_reality.map.ExtendedMapView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:id="@+id/map_view" 
android:apiKey="0zGaDxZvhGnutaf58dLLydh5riLex42FsZ7UKcA" />

</RelativeLayout>
```